# Worklight 7.1 - Push notification need to subscribe for last user in device who logged into app, previous user need to unsubscribe for that device

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an hybrid application developed with IBM Worklight 7.1 that receives push notification. This application use the username of user as userId to register to the push notification providers.

If the [userA] user is logout still he recieves notification but when new [userB]user login with same device how can i unsubscribe already existing user[userA] and we need to subscribe [userB]

Our scenario is
-->When user login he need to subscribe to push notification (Event source-based).

-->once he subscribed he will receive notification based on user name.

-->if he logout still he need to receive push notification.

--> Again when user tries to login into same mobile here first we need to unsubscribe is previous subscription and we need to subscribe.

Comment: Hybrid or native ? When a user already has a subscription, why do you want to unsubscribe upon a second login ? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: it is a Hybrid app.on a single device multiple user can login so we can't  subscribe for multiple user with a single device ,so we need to unsubscribe during new user login into app

Comment: One user cannot unsubscribe another one.

Comment: they how can i unsubscribe another one or old user before new user login

Comment: If the [userA] user is logout still he recieves notification but when new [userB]user login with same device how can i unsubscribe already existing user[userA] and we need to subscribe [userB]

Comment: Why do you need to unsubscribe userA? By logging in with UserB, once clicking on "subscribe", it is UserB that will get subscribed. It is perfectly OK to keep userA subscribed. It is the decision of userA whether to subscribe or remove subscription.

Comment: i have one device and multiple user can use that device i need to send a push notification  to lastly logged  user.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a user has already subscribed to the event source, you can use the API - [WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed(aliasname)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.Push.html%23isSubscribed?lang=en);

Note that from an application on a device, at any given time , there can only be one subscription to a particular eventsource. 
For example, consider App1 on Device1. Now user1 logs in and subscribes to eventsource ES1. The push subscription is recorded for user1 against ES1 from App1 on Device1.

Later user1 logs out and user2 logs in to App1. If user2 subscribes to ES1, the existing subscription is modified with user2 as the user.ie, it will become user2 against ES1 from App1 on Device1.

Hence, by design, your requirement is taken care of.

Comment: how can i modify subscription to user2 from user1...

WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed(aliasname) this will return true based on device subscription not user subscription.

Comment: How can i check user1 or user2 who ever logs in to App1 is a new user or old user  and whether they already subscribed from same device.

Comment: What makes you think WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed(aliasname) returns the value of device subscription. That is not true .
isSubscribed(aliasname) returns the state of user subscription and not device.

You cannot modify user subscription details of one user while logged in as another . That would be a major security risk. You can only check if the current logged in user has subscribed or not.

Comment: thanks Vivin k.  WL.Server.createEventSource({
 name: 'newCoupons',
 onUserSubscribe: 'subscribeUser',
 onUserUnsubscribe: 'unsubscribeUser',
 onUserChange: 'onUserChange',
 poll : {
 interval: 2,
 onPoll: 'produceNotifications'
 }
}); how can we call onUserChange, where we can use it

Comment: how i can make user1 unsubscribe from push notification before user2 login. because only one user can subscribe.

at the time of logout we are not making unsubscribe

Comment: Like I said, if your flow involves subscribing as soon as a user logs in, then user2 will take the place of user1 automatically.

Comment: "onUserChange" is a callback that executes as a result of the action. You cannot call it directly